# Hackerrank Weighted Average

Tags: python

The question can be found [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/s10-weighted-mean)

I'm trying to calculate the weighted average but when I try to populate an array with for loop It just doing nothing  ?

```
size = raw_input()
arr = raw_input()
w = raw_input()
deger = [1,2,2,2,2]


size = [int(i) for i in size.split()]
size = size[0]
arr = [int(i) for i in arr.split()]
w = [float(i) for i in w.split()] 


 def wm (x,y,s):
  for i in range(0,s-1):
    deger[i] = int(input(x[i]*y[i])) 


return sum(deger)



 print(wm(arr,w,size))
```

Comment: I hope your actual code doesn't have that wonky indentation! `def` should be up against the left margin and `return` indented. Anyway, you shouldn't use the `int(input(` when calculating `x[i]*y[i]`. You should also be `append()`ing to `deger`, not overwriting previous values.

Comment: I've tried appending but I get **can't assign to function call**  error .

Comment: First read the tutorial provided in the link since your calculation of the `weighted mean` is incorrect.

Comment: I should divide the "deger" value to sum of weights but I need to solve the loop problem first shouldn't i ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some modifications based on your code with proper indentation:

```
size = raw_input()
arr = raw_input()
w = raw_input()
#deger = [1,2,2,2,2] # not necessary to initialize 'deger' here


size = [int(i) for i in size.split()]
size = size[0]
arr = [int(i) for i in arr.split()]
w = [float(i) for i in w.split()] 


def wm (x,y,s):
    deger = [] # initialize empty 'deger' here
    for i in range(0,s): # 's-1' will not include the last item of x and y
        deger.append(x[i]*y[i])
    return sum(deger) / sum(y) 

print('%.1f'%wm(arr,w,size)) # as 1 decimal place is required
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `return` before printing the result.